# Подбор чисел из массива с суммой большей или равной К

Tags: java, массивы, алгоритм

Перечитал много материала, задача о ранце не подходит, потому что значение нужно либо большее (с минимальной разницей), либо равное заданному числу. Суть: есть массив из чисел, есть число. Задача: найти индексы чисел из массива, сумма которых либо минимально превышает, либо равна числу. Числа можно использовать неограниченное количество раз, но приоритет должен отдаваться более крупным числам (по возможности). Пишу на Java, но буду благодарен за реализацию или указание на любом языке программирования.

Простой пример: {202, 403}, заданное число: 604. Ответ: индексы 0 и 1. Эти числа в сумме дают 605, 202*3 даст 606 - не подходит, так как есть более подходящий вариант.
Другой пример: {202, 405}, заданное число: 604. Ответ: индексы 0, 0, 0. Сумма 606, другой вариант 607 - не подходит.

Код, который не работает:

```
var number = 603;
val coins = listOf<Int>(202, 404);
val result = HashMap<Int, Int>();
for (coin in coins) {
    val count = number / coin;
    number -= count * coin;
    if (count > 0) {
        result.put(coin, count)
    }
}
println(result)
```

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: @0-LevelUNIXMonk, это не учебное, а весьма практическое задание, которое должно быть применено в соответствующем программном обеспечении. Данные в массиве - это цены товаров, приведенные к целым числам, а заданное число - стоимость заказа. Я не стал уточнять эту информацию, чтобы не забивать голову людям, которые разбираются в вопросе и хотят помочь. Если вы к ним не относитесь, что ж, это уточнение для вас.

Comment: у вас есть минимальный код для воспроизведения?

Comment: @0-LevelUNIXMonk. У меня или есть код, или его нет. Какой смысл что-то писать, если я не знаю, как можно решить конкретно мою задачу?
Я добавил элементарнейший жадный алгоритм в вопрос, если вы настаиваете

Comment: значит домашка.

Comment: @0-LevelUNIXMonk, это потрясающее и непонятное мне упрямство, я еще раз повторяю, что это не относится к учебной деятельности, но переубеждать я вас более не собираюсь, мне это совершенно ни к чему.

Comment: задавайте вопросы, согласно правилам ресурса,  если не хотите не только минусов, но и не получить ответ.

Comment: @0-LevelUNIXMonk В данном случае вы не правы. У вопроса стоит тег "алгоритм" и ТС просит дать ему именно приемлемый алгоритм решения, а не реализацию не конкретном языке. В случае когда задают учебные задания  просят именно саму реализацию на конкретном языке, потому что не знают языка. Ни одного правила ресурса вопрос не нарушает

Comment: @Валентин Вы уверены, что указанных условий достаточно, если у вас будет {605, 2} при поиске 606 то правильным ответом будет 2*303. А не слишком ли большое количество слишком дешевых товаров вышло ?

Comment: @Mike, да, вы правы, такое вряд ли допустимо, оптимально использовать не более двух-трех позиций, но я постараюсь учесть эти ограничения на других этапах, а в данный момент нужно разобраться с тем алгоритмом, который предложил ув. @MBo)

Comment: @Валентин Лучше подобные ограничения продумать и оговорить как можно раньше. Один небольшой нюанс способен сделать тот или иной алгоритм оптимальным или совершенно неприемлемым

Answer (score 1):

Обычный subset sum с перехлёстом вверх.

Создать массив длиной "1 +нужная сумма + наибольшее число из массива", заполнить нулями, только в нулевой элемент записать -1 (не ноль, и не число из массива)

Для каждого элемента массива заполнить те ячейки, суммы в которых можно получить из имеющихся + данный элемент

```
 for coin in coins:
     for i = 0 .. sum-1:
         if A[i] !=0:
              A[i+coin] = coin
```

Если входной массив сортирован, то предпочтение более крупным получится при обходе с малых.

Comment: Благодарю за алгоритм, но с инициализацией массива А я не смог разобраться. Должен ли он выглядеть для чисел {1, 3}, K=4 следующим образом: `val sum = 4;
    val A = mutableListOf(-1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
    for (coin in listOf(1, 3)) {
        for (i in 0..sum - 1) {
            if (A[i] != 0) A[i + coin] = coin;
        }
    }`. Этот код вылетает с ошибкой. Если добавить в массив на один ноль больше, то результат получается следующий: `[-1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3]`

Comment: Изменил размер с учётом наибольшего числа, а не наименьшего (это будет с запасом, учитывающим предпочтение больших элементов). Да, для данного примера результат будет именно такой. A[4] = 3, значит 4 составлено из 3, плюс содержимое A[4-3]=A[1]=1, из A[1] попадаем в A[0] - раскрутка решения закончена. Если бы A[4] было нулём, нужно было бы проверить следующие ячейки.